# Как из вертикального списка - сделать горизонтальный

Tags: css3, html5, списки

Как из вертикального списка: [image: Вертикальный список]

Сделать, чтобы он был горизонтальный?
Вот кусочек кода:
[image: Кусочек кода]

Comment: Александр, не много не понял о чем вы? :)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `display: inline-block` для `li`

```css
.horisontal-ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="horisontal-ul">
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов несколько.

1 Варинат. C помощью `flex`:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* 1. Flex */
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Обучение</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Конференции</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">О нас</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

2 Вариант. `inline-block`:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* 2. inline-block */
nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Обучение</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Конференции</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">О нас</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

3 Вариант. `float: left`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* 3. float */
nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Обучение</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Конференции</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">О нас</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

4 Вариант. `table`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* 4. table */
nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Обучение</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Конференции</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">О нас</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}
li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
li:nth-child(1){
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Главная</li>
    <li>Обучения</li>
    <li>Конференция</li>
    <li>О нас</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```